# Lucene Solr custom tokenizer - How to include delimiter special characters as tokens?

Tags: solr, lucene, tokenize

I have a need to write a tokenizer for source code files in Solr, but don't have the option of including custom JARs. So for ex:

Input: `foo.bar`

Tokens: `'foo', '.', 'bar'`

How can I have a custom tokenizer or filter in schema.xml that can split on some characters, but also not drop the character ?

I tried Regex pattern tokenizer but that drops the delimiters.

Comment: What filters and tokenizers do you have configured right now?

Comment: I tried whitespace tokenizer because I did not want to drop special characters like :,@,-,+ etc. But I also want to split the tokens by ".", "+" and consider "." and "+" as separate tokens, meaning I don't want them to be dropped. I don't have any filter.

Comment: I did some research but could find a way short of writing your own tokenizer. Perhaps try emailing the Solr/Lucene mailing list http://lucene.apache.org/solr/community.html#mailing-lists-irc  Sorry I couldn't be of help